# How to get Spring, Hibernate, RESTful web service and Gradle working together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, gradle

I am trying to learn about Spring, Hibernate, RESTful web service and Gradle.

I came across these two tutorials.

**Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 + Gradle Integration Example using Annotation**

http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-hibernate-4-gradle-integration-example-using-annotation

**Building a RESTful Web Service**

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I tested the code locally and in both instances the code performs as expected.

Now I am trying to combine these two tutorials into one (made up) project that would use the Spring framework, Hibernate to connect to db via the RESTful web service and Gradle as the build tool.

In other words, I would like to accomplish the following:

I submit the following request via the url: **localhost:8080/country?countryname=France** in order to call the RESTful web service that will query my database (via Hibernate) and return the correct result in a JSON format.

I made somewhat progress but my configuration appears to be incorrect. My gradle build is successful but when I try to access localhost:8080/country I get:

This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here's my Gradle project:

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE")
        }
    }

    // DB
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


    //archivesBaseName = 'SpringHibernateRESTGradle'
    // version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT' 

    jar {
        baseName = 'countries-rest-service'
        version =  '0.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
       compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.1.4.RELEASE'
       compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
       compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
       compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
       compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
       compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
       compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'  
       // ws
       compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
       testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

**AppConfig**

```
    package com.pckg.config;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    import com.pckg.dao.CountryDAO;
    import com.pckg.dao.ICountryDAO;
    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public ICountryDAO getCountryDAO() {
            return new CountryDAO();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {

            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing_db");
            dataSource.setUsername("****");
            dataSource.setPassword("****");

            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource()).addAnnotatedClasses(Country.class).buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;

        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
            return new HibernateTemplate(getSessionFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager getHibernateTransManager() {
            return new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
        }

    }
```

**ServiceController**

```
    package com.pckg.controller;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    @RestController
    public class ServiceController {

        @RequestMapping("/country")
        public Country getCountryByName(@RequestParam(name = "countryname", required = false) String countryName) {

            // AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            // ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
            // ctx.refresh();
            //
            // ICountryDAO countryDAO = ctx.getBean(ICountryDAO.class);
            // Country country = countryDAO.getCountryByName(countryName);

            // just for testing purposes - still doesn't work
            Country c = new Country();
            c.setId(2);
            c.setCountry("France");
            c.setCapital("Paris");
            c.setContinent("Europe");
            return c;

        }

    }
```

**CountryDAO**

```
    package com.pckg.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;

    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    @Transactional
    public class CountryDAO implements ICountryDAO {

        @Autowired
        private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

        @Override
        public List<Country> getAllCountries() {

            String query = "from Country";

            List<Country> countries = (List<Country>) hibernateTemplate.find(query, null);

            // print out
            for (Country c : countries) {
                System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
                System.out.print(c.getCountry() + " ");
                System.out.print(c.getCapital() + " ");
                System.out.println(c.getContinent() + " ");
            }

            return countries;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Country> getCountriesByContinent(String continent) {

            String query = "from Country c where c.continent = :cntnt";

            List<Country> countries = (List<Country>) hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(query, "cntnt", continent);

            // print out
            for (Country c : countries) {
                System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
                System.out.print(c.getCountry() + " ");
                System.out.print(c.getCapital() + " ");
                System.out.println(c.getContinent() + " ");
            }
            return countries;
        }

        @Override
        public Country getCountryByName(String country) {

            String query = "FROM Country c WHERE c.country = : cntry";
            Country countryResult = (Country) hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(query, "cntry", country);

            return countryResult;
        }

    }
```

**ICountryDAO**

```
    package com.pckg.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    public interface ICountryDAO {

        public List<Country> getAllCountries();

        public List<Country> getCountriesByContinent(String continent);

        public Country getCountryByName(String country);
    }
```

**Country**

```
    package com.pckg.entity;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "countries")
    public class Country {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;

        @Column(name = "capital")
        private String capital;

        @Column(name = "continent")
        private String continent;

        // no arg constructor
        public Country() {

        }

        public Country(int id, String country, String capital, String continent) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.country = country;
            this.capital = capital;
            this.continent = continent;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getCapital() {
            return capital;
        }

        public void setCapital(String capital) {
            this.capital = capital;
        }

        public String getContinent() {
            return continent;
        }

        public void setContinent(String continent) {
            this.continent = continent;
        }

    }
```

**CountryService**

```
    package com.pckg.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import com.pckg.dao.ICountryDAO;
    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    public class CountryService implements ICountryService {

        @Autowired
        private ICountryDAO countryDAO;

        @Override
        public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
            return countryDAO.getAllCountries();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Country> getCountriesByContinent(String continent) {
            return countryDAO.getCountriesByContinent(continent);
        }

        @Override
        public Country getCountryByName(String country) {
            return countryDAO.getCountryByName(country);
        }

    }
```

**ICountryService**

```
    package com.pckg.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.pckg.entity.Country;

    public interface ICountryService {

        public List<Country> getAllCountries();

        public List<Country> getCountriesByContinent(String continent);

        public Country getCountryByName(String country);
    }
```

**Application**

```
    package com.pckg.test;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Any suggestions how to get my code working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I added the following code to my gradle.build file:

```
    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
```

It fixed the original issue but I am getting a new error after running "gradlew bootRun"

```
            [main] WARN org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
            [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
            org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
                    at com.pckg.test.Application.main(Application.java:10)
            Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
                    ... 8 more
            :bootRun FAILED

            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have researched the issue but I couldn't find a fix for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding @Service on your service impl and interface.

About ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, is your server running properly? Can you post the spring boot-up log? @Entity and @RestController parts are looking ok, not sure about the dao.

Also i might suggest you to work with https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ using application.properties to connect to you db. A much cleaner and faster expererience.